# Facing problem in partitioning in ubuntu installation ( alongside windows)

Tags: partitioning

I want to install ubuntu alongside of windows. I created unallocated space in windows. But it is not showing as free space in ubuntu installation. How to create free space for ubuntu installation

Even I created drive with the unallocated space in windows, it is not showing in ubuntu installation.
C drive - 100 gb
D drive - 140 gb
E drive - 190 gb
Unallocated - 50 gb
System reserved - 100mb

In ubuntu installation it is showing only 3 ntfs with the following space
                                         Size.         Used
/dev/sda
/dev/sda1  ntfs           1mb.          Unknown
/dev/sda2.  ntfs      104 mb.        Unknown
/dev/sda3. ntfs.     104751mb.      14349mb
/dev/sda4  ntfs.     395249mb.      160737mb
Which partition I have to select now for installation

I tried after creating drive with the unallocated space but it is showing same as the above.

Where is the 50gb space in which I want to install ubuntu

I am using 14.04.3 LTS

Comment: Don't summarize. Show us actual program output -- either screen shots of GParted or cut-and-pasted text-mode output from `parted`, `fdisk`, or `gdisk` (as appropriate for your disk type). The version of Windows and partitioning scheme (MBR or GPT) are also relevant.

Answer (score 0):

In a "standard" configuration, it would be the `/dev/sdc2` partition.

Assuming you are using `gparted`, there is a drive toggle up to the right, where you can select the third drive (corresponding to E:).